# "bookmark" a lisp code block and launch through emacs bookmarking system

Tags: bookmarks

I googled for this with no success. im looking to "bookmark" a lisp code block so that it appears in the emacs/bookmark+ bookmark lists. for example i want to launch this lisp code when i launch a bookmark "xxz"

```
(defun xxz ()
 "jump"
  (interactive)
  (bmkp-dired-jump "h.nyc" )
  (org-narrow-to-subtree)
   )
```

anyone know if this is possible at all?

Comment: You might also consider using either `bookmark-after-jump-hook` or `bmkp-before-jump-hook`. You also have `bmkp-jump-display-function`. And you can put predefined bookmark tag `"bmkp-jump"` on any bookmark - give it any function as value - see [Tags as Attributes](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#TagsAsAttributes).

Comment: hmm cool. so i tried this `T v bmkp-jump RET (lambda () (org-narrow-to-subtree))` with no apparent success. is that correct syntax?

Comment: Yes. What does `(bmkp-get-tag-value BOOKMARK "bmkp-jump")` tell you for your `BOOKMARK`? Be sure that the right buffer is really current when you invoke `org-narrow-to-subtree` (I know nothing about that function, but its doc talks about the current buffer).

Comment: this is the output `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable h\.nyc)
  (bmkp-get-tag-value h\.nyc "bmkp-jump")
  eval((bmkp-get-tag-value h\.nyc "bmkp-jump") nil)
  eval-expression((bmkp-get-tag-value h\.nyc "bmkp-jump") nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression (bmkp-get-tag-value h\.nyc "bmkp-jump") nil)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression)`

Comment: ah, i does seem to work..i could have sworn yesterday it didnt narrow..i did restart emacs server today..but hey as long as it works ;-) thx!

Comment: Start with the hooks: `bookmark-after-jump-hook` or `bmkp-before-jump-hook`. If they don't fit your use case then consider the other means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have read the bookmark+ deeper. There is a way to do that with

```
bmkp-make-function-bookmark
```

This works perfectly.